# PHP Problem with foreach loop with YouTube API

Tags: php, youtube-api

I found and modified a snippet for displaying youtube videos.

I set it up behind BootStrap using Models to popup when clicked.

Problem I'm having is figuring out why the fourth item isn't showing the popup model.

If you want to see the problem in action you can click the fourth item listed in the bottom at: https://phattboiibamm.com/

```
<?php 
//Get videos from channel by YouTube Data API
$API_key    = 'SECRET'; //my API key
$channelID  = 'SECRET'; //my channel ID
$maxResults = 4;

$video_list = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));


$latest = $video_list->items[0]->id->videoId;
$thelist = $video_list->items;
?>
```

This is the loop

```
            <?php
foreach ($thelist as $item) {

    //Embed video
    if (isset($item->id->videoId)) {
        //echo '<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-21by9">
       //         <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                //<h4>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h4>
       //     </div>';
       
       echo "\n \n <br><br> \n \n ";
       echo "\n \n <!-- Image --> \n \n";
       echo "\n \n <br><br> \n \n ";
       
           echo '<img src="'.$item->snippet->thumbnails->high->url.'" width="250px" height="250px" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#'.$item->id->videoId.'">';
       
       echo "\n \n <br><br> \n \n ";
       echo "\n \n <!-- Model --> \n \n";
       echo "\n \n <br><br> \n \n ";
       
        echo '<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="'.$item->id->videoId.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    
                    <center><h4>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h4></center>
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9 z-depth-1-half">
                        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item p-1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>';
       
       
    } 

} ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem here is that you have an `id` attribute, which starts with the **number** (in your markup it is **7**):

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="7hJv63L6Sco" ...
```

Some browsers (maybe even all) don't work with id values, starting with numbers. So, to avoid this you can prepend `id` with some string, e.g.:

```
echo '<img src="'.$item->snippet->thumbnails->high->url.'" width="250px" height="250px" alt="..." class="img-thumbnail m-1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#video-'.$item->id->videoId.'">';
   
//  and here
echo '<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="video-'.$item->id->videoId.'" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

Note, that `data-target` attribute should be changed too.

Useful link (thanks @04FS) for using numeric and other non-regular symbols as attributes' values : https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes

Comment: Absolutely fixed the problem! Thank you very much. I didn't know that the id attributes couldn't start with a numeric character.

Comment: @BinaryAccepted they _can_ start with a digit, from the HTML5 perspective - but using them directly in CSS selectors might fail then, you’d need additional escaping to make that work, see https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes